# How to get index of tag in loop?

Tags: html, playframework, playframework-1.x

I just start with create loop in html as following:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="course_div" style="float: left; width: 100%;">

    #{list items:timeSlotDetails, as:'timeDetails' }

        <div id="div_0" class="copyDiv" />
        <select id="dayOne" name="dayOne" />

    #{/list}
</div>
```

So, there are so many `<div>` in list and I want to get index of `<select>` to initiate

value. However, I dont know how to get element in this list. Please help me, thank you.

However, I can get the element by using `$('#div_0 #dayOne')[index]`.

Comment: That isn't HTML. It would help if you mentioned the template language you were using.

Comment: Obviously, this is not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

[Officiall documntation says](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/tags#list) that should be:

```
#{list items:timeSlotDetails, as:'timeDetails' }
     ${timeDetails_index}
#{/list}
```

Note that's **1** based index